# Grouping table with data headers

Tags: php, html

Hi everyone im attempting to group my data table to display the users listed by department eg:

```
                     IT DEPARTMENT
Name       Phone     Email           Extension
Bob        99393     ksand@sda       8484
```

but mine is displayed as this:

```
Name       Phone     Email           Extension    Department
Bob        99393     ksand@sda       8484            IT
```

I did some reading on datatable grouping but coulodnt find anything that explains how it works and how to implement it.

My code is below. If someone could point me to a link to help that would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

```
    <?php 
    require_once"connection.php";

    $contacts = array();

    $all_contacts = "select * from contacts where contact_status = '1'";


    $sql_all_contacts = $conn->query($all_contacts);

    $total_contacts = $sql_all_contacts->num_rows;

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql_all_contacts)) {
            $contacts[] = $row;
    }
?>
<html>
<head>
    <?php include"includes/head.inc"; ?>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">

            <!-- header section -->
            <?php include"includes/header.inc"; ?>

            <!-- content section -->
            <div class="content">
                    <div class="floatl"><h1><?php echo $total_contacts ?> Contact(s) Total</h1></div>
                    <a class="floatr" href="insert_contact.php"><input class="cancel_contact_button" type="button" value="New Contact"></a>    $
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                            <hr class="pageTitle">
                            <table border ="1" style="width:100%" id="contactsTable" class="display">
             <thead>
             <tr align="left">
             <th>Name:</th>
             <th>Email:</th>
             <th>Department:</th>
             <th>Extension:</th>
             <th>Cellphone:</th>
             <th>Actions</th>
             </tr> 
             </thead>

 <tr align="left">
           <th>Name:</th>
           <th>Email:</th>
           <th>Department:</th>
           <th>Extension:</th>
           <th>Cellphone:</th>
           <th>Actions</th>
           </tr> 
            </thead>
            <tbody>
           <?php foreach ($contacts as $contact) {?>
            <tr>
          <td><?php echo $contact["name"];?></td>
          <td><?php echo $contact["email"]; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $contact["department"]; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $contact["extension"]; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $contact["cellphone"]; ?></td>
        <td><a href="update_contact.php?id=<?php echo $contact["contact_id"]; ?>"><i class="fa fa-p$
           </tr>
           <?php } ?>
           </tbody>
           </table>
            </div>
    </div>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: is the above one is what you are expected?...

Comment: @J.Zend not expecting. im trying to make it do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're already doing a `while` loop to add the db rows into an array, you could use the Department as the key. This would group the contacts by department, and you could run nested `foreach` loops.

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql_all_contacts)) {
    $contacts[$row['Department']][] = $row;
}
```

The `foreach` loops:

```
foreach ($contacts as $department => $contactGroup) {
    echo $department;
    foreach($contactGroup as $contact) {
        // output your contact here
    }
}
```

Comment: where would i put this code? i assume i overwrite my  "while" script with yours. but where would i put the foreach loop code and do i need to add anything?

Comment: Sorry if it wasn't clear. You replace your current foreach loop with the nested loops I provided and you add the appropriate output. `$department` can be added to a header row, and you can output the `$contact` data in the same we you did before.